# How to detect closing a popup but not fetching a website

Tags: javascript, html

I'm running an app in a popup window. I have the following code in the head of my html file for one particular site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function navigate() {
        window.location.href = "{{ next_page }}";
      }
    fetch("{{ next_page }}").then(navigate);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
        window.opener.location.replace("some-link");
    })
</script>
```

The goal is to show the current page until another page loads (thus `fetch.then(navigate)`) and -- at the same time -- be able to spot that the user closed the popup and redirect the user to another website whenever that happens.

The problem is, the parent window redirects to another website (`some-link`) after 'next_page' loads.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? Can I use the `fetch.then` construction and still be able to spot the user closed the popup window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a globally available variable, set and access as appropriate. The following is a guide only and will need to be adjusted to suite your needs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.detectUnload = true;
    function navigate() {
        window.detectUnload = false;
        window.location.href = "{{ next_page }}";
      }
    fetch("{{ next_page }}").then(navigate);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
       if(window.detectUnload){window.opener.location.replace("some-link")}
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively you could use [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) , but it could be tricky with the way your code is scoped in different script elements.

Comment: Ahh, ok, I haven't tried hiding the global variable inside the `navigate` function because I thought it is a lost cause. Dummy. Thanks!